# Jekyll offsetting initial line of code snippet highlighting

Tags: html, css, jekyll, pygments

So I'm setting up code highlighting on my blog using Jekyll and Pygments, and the first line of every snippet is offset by some infinitesimal amount. I'm trying to use a right-border of the `lineno` class to create a gutter, which is making the offset very apparent, as seen below

[image: offset]

Here is the DOM when I inspect the relevant area,

[image: css tree]

and here is the source:

[image: view source]

Here is the relevant CSS Source:

```
.highlight code {
    background:#3A434A;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', Monaco, monospace;
    }
.highlight pre {
    background:#3A434A;
pre .lineno { 
    color: #eff1f5; 
    display:inline-block; 
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 0px; 
    border-right:1px solid #8fa1b3
}
```

This is infuriating me, hahah; I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. I get consistent behavior across all browsers. Also, [Here's](http://oflannabhra.github.io/code/2014/trello-hash/) a link if you'd like to view it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Jekyll css

```
pre > code {
  border: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0; }
```

**code** padding-left needs to be **0**.

Comment: aweseom! thanks a bundle! Any idea why the padding was affecting the first line that way but not the others?

Comment: Sorry I'm not a css guru, I just get this from the **F12** debug. But if it's not a bug, it's a feature ;-)

Comment: For some reason, I'm guessing that the `<code>` tag has no width or height, even though Dev Tools shows it as wrapping the child. The browser is actually applying this padding "in between" the `<pre>` and the first child element of the `<code>`